# Accessing a javascript method from the cshtml in Asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a cshtml file and a button that on click calls a javascript method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PlayGameRound", "Games", new { id = Model.GameId, 
category = Model.Category }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Play" style="float: left" id="play" onclick="@Model.Category = play()"/>
</div>

}
```

This is the javascript file method that is called.

```
function play() {
if (hideSpin) {
    return category;
  }
}
```

When i am running my program the javascript method is never called. How would I ensure the method is called when the button is clicked?

Comment: Its just `onclick="play()`. But you cannot assign it to a model property (razor is server side code)

Comment: I added just the play() now but how do I pass it to the controller method I have when submit is hit when I do not give the return value to something? Does it automatically go when I hit submit under the name category?

Comment: We have no idea what your trying to do here. What is `hideSpin`? What is `category`? What is it that you want to post back to the controller and bind to you model?